# Set no type for a static method in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Not a fan of Java, but Java allows not setting types for generic classes and in that case it threats the type as `Object` type. However, as far as I know, C# enforces setting the type of `<T>` anytime the generic class has to be instantiated or simply speaking used. However, let's say that we have a generic class, and we need a static method in there which does not rely on the type of `<T>`.

Firstly, we know that it can be moved to a separate context or we can set a dummy type of `<T>`, but as a programming puzzle is there any way to call it **Without defining the type of `T`**?

Example:

```
 class Test<T> where T: ITestable {
     ...
     public static void CreateTestFile(String fileName) {...}
 }
 Test.CreateTestFile("test.txt");
```

This can be done Java and apparently can't be in C#. But I just wanna make sure.

Comment: NO, the type has to filled while calling or at compile time it can't be kept opened as `T`. You should consider separating the static method out this generic class.

Comment: It just the matter of curiosity. As I said I just wanted to make sure C# doesn't allow it.

Comment: Just put the method in a non-generic class... If it's not related to `T`, it has no reason to be in `Test<T>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java and C# implement generics differently:

- Java uses *type erasure*, which basically means that at compile time, anything you put in `<T>` is erased and becomes `Object`. `Something<Foo>` and `Something<Bar>` will be the same type at runtime, and wil be effectively equal to `Something<Object>`.
- C# uses *run-time reification*, meaning that for each type you use with a distinct `T`, the runtime generates a new class altogether, by using the open generic version as a template (which means it also generates the underlying native code once per `T` as you call it). `Something<Foo>` and `Something<Bar>` are two unrelated types as far as the CLR is concerned.

Hopefully you understand why this difference is important to your scenario. Ignoring `T` is trivial in Java, but not so easy in C#.

If you don't need `T` in your code, then use a non-generic method:

```
abstract class Test
{
    public static void CreateTestFile(String fileName) {...}
}

class Test<T> : Test
    where T : ITestable
{
     ...
}
```

Here, that's better :)

Also, note that for instance methods, you can use *covariant* and *contravariant* interfaces to loosen the requirement for a known `T` at compile-time. For instance, if you use a covariant interface, you only need to know a base type of `T`.

Comment: Nice answer. Didn't knew about the Java's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider separating your concerns, placing that public static method elsewhere. However, if you really want to call it, this would work just fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test<ITestable>.CreateTestFile("test.txt");
    }
}

class Test<T> where T : ITestable
{
     public static void CreateTestFile(String fileName) { }
}

public interface ITestable { }
```

If you had a constraint `where T : class, new()`, you could do something similar:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test<object>.CreateTestFile("test.txt");
    }
}

class Test<T> where T : class, new()
{
     public static void CreateTestFile(String fileName) { }
}

public interface ITestable { }
```

If you had an even weirder constraint like `where T : class, ITestable, new()` I'd stop worrying about getting the compiler to jump through your hoops, rethink your design, and separate the concerns along these lines:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Util.CreateTestFile("test.txt");
    }
}

class Util
{
    public static void CreateTestFile(String fileName) { }
}

class Test<T> where T : class, ITestable, new()
{
    /*...*/
}

public interface ITestable { }
```

Comment: Imagine the T is `where T: class, new()`, and you don't wanna set the type. Then it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah exactly, but when you look at something from various angles, more scenarios come into the view.

Comment: Maybe, but you do run a risk of creating a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/162730), which is not much fun for answerers.

Comment: and again (not trying to be mean :D) imagine it is `where T: class, ITestable, new()`.